# Can't copy value from the Last Row to other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have situation such as this:

```
 Sub AutoSum()
     Dim Sumcalc As Double
     Dim LR As Long
     Dim Sm As Range

     Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = _
      WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
    
    LR = Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Range("E" & LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("I1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

and I cannot copy the value from the last row to the other worksheet. It returns a blank cell.
How can I copy the value from the last row to the cell located in other sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlCellTypeLastCell` not necessarily gives the last cell with data (can for example be the last row that has some formatting). You use another technique two lines before using `End` - why not write this into a variable and reuse it?

Have a look to the following snippet.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
    .Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E2:E" & lastRow + 1))
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("I1").Value = .Range("E" & lastRow + 1).Value
End With
```